# MySql version 8.0.17 exclude rows where NOT LIKE and OR condition

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a part of list records in the table stored a database MySql version 8.0.17

```
+---------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
| tkt           | tdate               | tstate    | tigx                | tclosed             | tcompleted |
+---------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
| 098720D045584 | 2020-12-21 21:22:00 | Forwarded | 2021-01-05 10:24:00 | NULL                | NULL       |
| 098720B045582 | 2020-12-21 20:15:00 | Forwarded | 2021-01-05 10:27:00 | NULL                | NULL       |
| 098720B045560 | 2020-12-21 17:02:00 | Forwarded | 2021-01-05 10:19:00 | NULL                | NULL       |
| 098720B045549 | 2020-12-21 16:36:00 | Forwarded | 2021-01-05 10:08:00 | NULL                | NULL       |
| 098720B045537 | 2020-12-21 14:57:00 | Forwarded | 2021-01-05 10:33:00 | NULL                | NULL       |
| 098720D045536 | 2020-12-21 14:57:00 | Closed    | NULL                | 2020-12-21 17:39:00 | NULL       |
| 098720L045296 | 2020-12-21 09:00:00 | Closed    | NULL                | NULL                | NULL       |
| 098720B045470 | 2020-12-21 08:55:00 | Forwarded | 2021-01-05 10:21:00 | NULL                | NULL       |
+---------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.14 sec)
```

I have to exclude this row from return

```
+---------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
| tkt           | tdate               | tstate    | tigx                | tclosed             | tcompleted |
+---------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
| 098720L045296 | 2020-12-21 09:00:00 | Closed    | NULL                | NULL                | NULL       |
+---------------+---------------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+
```

Because

1. the number of `tkt` contains **L** letter
2. the `tstate` is **closed**
3. the `tigx` is **NULL**
4. the `tclosed` is **NULL**
5. the `tcompleted` is **NULL**

I have tried without success this query because the row is present in return sql

```
SELECT
    tkt,
    tdate,
    tstate,
    tigx,
    tclosed,
    tcompleted
FROM
    `tbl_c` 
WHERE
    ((
        `tkt` NOT LIKE '%I%' 
    OR  `tkt` NOT LIKE '%L%' AND tstate IN ( 'Closed' ) AND tigx IS NULL AND tclosed IS NULL AND tcompleted IS NULL )) 
ORDER BY
    tdate DESC;
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? I would assume that you got the conditions wrong, brackets could help

Comment: @NicoHaase Debug?

Comment: Expression `X NOT Y OR X NOT Z` is always true. And that is what you have there.

Comment: @ex4 what's your suggestion?

Comment: A suggestion to debug the problem: check the conditions row by row. This is even possible by hand

Comment: @EdwardSheriffCurtis: Write with pseudo language what you want. It isn't clear here. There is one answer already, does it meet your need? Do you exclude all rows having I in TKT field and also exclude some subset of rows having L in tkt-field and meet some other conditions as well?

Comment: If you have an AND and OR you should be looking to clarify the conditions with brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating your requirements literally:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tbl_c
WHERE NOT (tkt LIKE '%L%' AND tstate = 'Closed' AND tigx IS NULL AND
           tclosed IS NULL AND tcompleted IS NULL);
```

Comment: Resultset of this query includes rows with character `I` in field `tkt`. I suppose that this isn't wanted effect.

Comment: @ex4 The other requirements in the actual SQL also confused me.  As they were never described in the question, I ignored them.

Answer (score 1):

Conditions like this perhaps:

```
WHERE 
    tkt NOT LIKE '%I%'  
  AND NOT
   (tkt LIKE '%L%' 
    AND tstate = 'Closed'  
    AND tigx IS NULL 
    AND tclosed IS NULL 
    AND tcompleted IS NULL )) 
    AND LEFT ( `tigx`, 1 ) NOT IN ( 'M' ) 
   )
```

This *excludes* following rows:

- all rows where field tkt has char I
- rows where filed tkt has char L and other conditions mentioned in your original query are met.